# Reported speech uncertainty

Tags: reported-speech, backshifting

Can you help me with these?

Which of them are correct or sound more natural? 
How far into the sentence does the reported speech go- I feel like if I transform everything it changes the meaning and the time reference- past instead of the present.

---

I miss you.

1. I'd lie if I said I didn't miss you
2. I'd lie if I said I don't miss you.

---

He's not performing up to par.

1. I'd lie if I said he was performing up to par.
2. I'd lie if I said he is performing up to par.

---

What if I want it to mean this:

He's been performing up to par. (Some backshifting should take place, right?)

1.I'd lie if I said he'd been performing up to par. (turning present perfect in past perfect)

2. I'd lie if I said he's been performing up to par.

---

How about backshifting and tense agreement in general?

For instance:

"What are you gonna do tough guy?" "I was thinking of slapping you around till you cried/ till you cry."

Answer (score 1):

Note that we usually say "I'd *be* lying if..."

Either of your options is can be heard, but the past tense is preferred. It can be read as an *irrealis* supporting the conditional, meaning that it's not actually the past. Compare to these expressions that are hypothetical rather than past:

> If I had a million dollars, I would...
>
> If I were king, I would...

You'll notice that your sentences essentially invert this structure.

That said, by using another tense, such as the present, you can remove any ambiguity.

> I'd be lying if I said I didn't love you.
>   
> <sub>*Realis* past or *irrealis* present</sub>
>
> I'd be lying if I said never loved you.
>   
> <sub>*Realis* past only, but scope is different</sub>
>
> I'd be lying if I said I don't love you.
>   
> <sub>*Realis* present only, but may be frowned on by some</sub>

This also applies to compound tenses:

> I'd be lying if I said I wasn't going to marry you.
>   
> <sub>Are those plans still on or not?!</sub>
>
> I'd be lying if I said I'm not going to marry you.
>   
> <sub>The plans are still on, but may be frowned on for the tense mismatch</sub>